# Create typescript file and import it right after

Tags: deno

Trying to do this:

```
await Deno.create(import.meta.resolve('./example.ts').replace('file://', ''))
await Deno.writeTextFile(import.meta.resolve('./example.ts').replace('file://', ''), `export const test = true`)
const { test } = await import('./example.ts')
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 encoded import:

```
import { encode } from "https://deno.land/std@0.99.0/encoding/base64.ts";
const url = new URL(`data:application/typescript;base64,${encode(`export const test = true`)}`)
const v = await import(url.href)
console.log(v)
```